# query eloquent can't where id = value

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to query select join and there's a condition where and I get a problem when the state of status is approve to be udenfined column. Please help me.

error

> QLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
> LINE 1: ...st_id" where "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request"."status" = ?;                                                                        ^ (SQL: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pur_tra_purchase_request_outstanding_pr AS select "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request_detail"."id", "item_id", "uom", "qty", "unit_price", "eta", "justification", "currency_code", "cancel_flag", "cancel_qty", "lead_time", "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request"."status" from "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request_detail" inner join "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request" on "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request"."id" = "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request_detail"."pur_tra_purchase_request_id" where "dbsc"."pur_tra_purchase_request"."status" = ?;)"

my query laravel

```
$sql = DB::table('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail')
    ->select(
        'dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail.id',
        'item_id',
        'uom',
        'qty',
        'unit_price',
        'eta',
        'justification',
        'currency_code',
        'cancel_flag',
        'cancel_qty',
        'lead_time',
        'dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request.status')
    ->join(
        'dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request',
        'dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request.id',
        '=',
        'dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail.pur_tra_purchase_request_id')
    ->where('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request.status', "approved")
    ->toSql();
```

Comment: Check your code above this SQL line is there any semicolon missing??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written your query syntax wrong in the where clause

```
$sql = DB::table('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail')
  ->select('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail.id','item_id','uom','qty','unit_price','eta','justification','currency_code','cancel_flag','cancel_qty'
           ,'lead_time','dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request.status')
  ->join('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request',
             'dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request.id','=','dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request_detail.pur_tra_purchase_request_id')
  ->where('dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request.status','=','approved')->toSql();
```

Hope this works for you :)

Comment: dbsc.pur_tra_purchase_request.status what does DBSC defines?

Comment: and what is pur_tra_purchase_request_detail?

Comment: Are you joining a table inside the same table??

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:- please write the table name in select query with . (for e.g. `pur_tra_purchase_request_detail.id`) in front of every row

```
$sql = DB::table('pur_tra_purchase_request_detail')
      ->select('pur_tra_purchase_request_detail.id','item_id','uom','qty','unit_price','eta','justification','currency_code','cancel_flag','cancel_qty'
               ,'lead_time','pur_tra_purchase_request.status')
          ->join('pur_tra_purchase_request',
                 'pur_tra_purchase_request.id','pur_tra_purchase_request_detail.pur_tra_purchase_request_id')
          ->where('pur_tra_purchase_request.status','approved')->toSql();
```